# GPSD not getting a good fix

Tags: gps, raspberry-pi, tty, gpsd

I have a GPS module connected to a Raspberry Pi via USB.

For some reason I can't seem to get a fix using:

> cgps

it doesn't seem to get a fix and terminates.

I've also tried:

> sudo killall gpsd
>
> sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock

and then tried cgps again, but that doesn't seem to work either.

I even tried:

> sudo nano /etc/default/gpsd

and changed the line:

> GPSD_OPTIONS=""

to:

> GPSD_OPTIONS="/dev/ttyACM0"

which apparently worked for others around the web, but after a reboot, that didn't work either.

But for some reason when I do:

> gpsmon /dev/ttyUSB0

I get a full readout of data; lat, lon, Sats, altitude, ext.

Is there a way to output `gpsmon /dev/ttyUSB0` sentences to a text file?

Also, why can't I obtain a fix using cgps or something similar?

Comment: Could not get gpsd to even output anything but your gpsmon /dev/ttyUSB0 command worked +1

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this issue, the accepted answer did not work for me, however this did the trick in half the steps: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28483/cgps-gps-timeout/50133#50133

Comment: run gpsd with -D4 -n -N and show us the logs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[gpsd](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/) is a beautiful application to simplify gps use, but it can be a little confusing.

If you're using a Rasbian, or some `apt` based package system it is best to configure it with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gpsd` to avoid complications (tyqos), but isn't necessary.  We have preferences for, but you may not,

- autostart,
- `-n` Don't wait for a client
- `-G` to listen on all addresses,
- `-b` Broken-device-safety mode, and
- auto*find*

The resultant configuration file looks like

```
# Default settings for gpsd.
# Please do not edit this file directly - use `dpkg-reconfigure gpsd'  to
# change the options.
START_DAEMON="true"
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -G -b"
DEVICES=""
USBAUTO="true"
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

The primary stumbling block with this approach while gpsd is running in this fashion is it will grab the gps before you can.  Attempts to independently and directly access the device `/dev/whatever` will fail as busy.

If you wish to go that route, for whatever reason, before doing anything else, make sure gpsd is not running.

`sudo killall gpsd`

and remove any sockets gpsd might have left behind,

`sudo rm /var/run/gpsd.sock`

Check the location of your gps by attaching it and tracking where it went with `dmesg | tail`.  It will look something like

```
[67338.935645] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[67338.935650] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[67338.935653] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[67338.936154] pl2303 1-1.2:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[67338.937953] usb 1-1.2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[67339.806917] pl2303 ttyUSB1: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[67339.807306] pl2303 ttyUSB1: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[67340.018016] pps_ldisc: PPS line discipline registered
[67340.018321] pps pps0: new PPS source usbserial1
[67340.018330] pps pps0: source "/dev/ttyUSB1" added
```

Then you can check for output with `sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB1`...or whatever, but you could do that with gpsd running.  (You can also pump this into a text file `sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB1 > gps_dump.txt`, or your `gpsmon /dev/ttyUSB0 >gps_dump.txt`, but there are more elegant solutions.)

The flip side of the confusion is no gps output from the gpsd because it isn't running or configured 'properly'. (either turned off, not started, or pointing to the wrong device).  A few application will tell you it's not running, many just sit in silence without any data.  I know of none that will tell you gpsd has been manually set to the wrong device.

If you have killed gpsd, or do not have it auto*magically* start, ensure that it is running with `sudo /etc/init.d/gpsd restart`

Unless you're doing something odd with odd hardware *most* cases will spit back data with gpsd in these settings, sparing the need for diagnostic settings.

However, bear in mind `cgps` will timeout if there is no fix.  Check your skyview, and [Time To First Fix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_fix). `xgps`, on the other hand, is more resilient for failures and provides clues for the absence, or quality of data.   If you have an X server, `xgps` is actually my preferred test for "is it working".  If you don't, but have your Pi on a network (`xgps 192.168.0.6`, or whatever, because the other machine has gpsd-client installed).  Another  option is to `ssh -X user@192.168.0.6` and then execute `xgps`)

Telneting into gpsd, while interesting, is another tier diagnostic, as are others.

And finally, a shameless plug for a [Python client for gpsd (gps3.py)](https://github.com/wadda/gps3) as means to access the data from a gpsd. It still is alpha, but it doesn't import historical cruft.

Comment: Awesome explanation of the process! As you said above, I think a lot of the confusion I had was because the various tools like cgps and xgps dont  acknowledge or show the state of gpsd. I'll give what you said a try. Maybe my problem was with not "removing" any sockets. I'll keep you updated as I experiment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

You may be binding to the wrong serial. You discover the serial for your GPS device by navigating to the folder below without the device plugged in, then refreshing with the device plugged in.

```
cd /dev/
ls
```

My device is called "ttyACM0"

Install the requisite packages.

```
sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients python-gps
```

Stop Daemons

```
sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket
sudo systemctl disable gpsd.socket
```

Expose Service to public ports and localhost

```
vim /lib/systemd/system/gpsd.socket
```

Change 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0

Stop GPSD services

```
sudo killall gpsd
```

Bind service to serial device

```
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyACM0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```

Show GPS Data

```
gpsmon
```

This video shows step by step how to do what you are looking for.

How to install GPS on RaspberryPi

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1zmhxcUOxw